# How to give a structure with arrays in simulink to a custom C code function?

Tags: c, matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I'm trying to give a structure to a C function in Simulink. My steps so far:

- Included the `.h` & `.c` in configuration parameters custom code. My header has a structure defind:

  ```
  typedef struct mystruct   
  {  int m; 
  int *i; 
  double *x;}mystruct
  ```
- Now in my MATLAB function under Simulink:

  ```
  function y = fcn(u)%#codegen   
  m=int32(1);
  i=zeros(10,1,'int32');
  x=zeros(10,1); 
  s.m=m;
  s.i=i;
  s.x=x;
  coder.cstructname(s,'mystruct','extern');
  D=int32(0);
  D=coder.ceval('accesmystruct',coder.ref(s));
  y=10;
  ```

If I run the code I get a long error from the code generation that indicates that it can't be compiled in c-code. The error is:

```
   c2_Test2.c 
   c2_Test2.c(57) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*' 
   c2_Test2.c(57) : error C2081: 'cs_size' : name in formal parameter   list illegal 
   c2_Test2.c(57) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*' 
   c2_Test2.c(57) : error C2059: syntax error : ')' 
   c2_Test2.c(60) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'   
   ....
```

This only happens if I declare the two variables `i` and `x` as Pointers. If I declare them as scalar in the header and MATLAB function it works.
Does any one see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Getting the Code to Compile**

To get the code to compile I added:

```
#include "mystruct.h"
```

in the Simulation Target->Custom Code->Header File section. Adding the required include paths on that pane may be necessary as well.

**Compatibility Concerns**

After doing the above, the code crashes when running. The issue is that the definition of `mystruct` is not what MATLAB Coder is expecting.

When you define a MATLAB structure with fixed-size arrays inside of it, the type generated by MATLAB Coder uses static arrays inside of the C struct like:

```
typedef struct {
  int32_T m;
  int32_T i[10];
  real_T x[10];
} mystruct;
```

You can see this in the code in the `slprj` directory if you remove the `'extern'` from the `coder.cstructname` call.

A struct with inline arrays already has memory allocated for the arrays by the C compiler. However, when the fields are pointers, someone needs to allocate the space for the data, which has not been done here.

I see a few options:

- Omit the `'extern'` and allow MATLAB Coder/Simulink to generate the type definition
- Declare your external structure with arrays rather than pointers for `i` and `x`
- Before writing to or reading from the struct, pass it to another C function that allocates memory for the fields:

  ```
  function y = fcn(u)
  %#codegen
  m=int32(1);
  i=zeros(10,1,'int32');
  x=zeros(10,1);
  s = coder.nullcopy(struct('m',m,'i',i,'x',x));
  coder.cstructname(s,'mystruct');
  coder.ceval('initmystruct',coder.wref(s),int32(numel(i)),int32(numel(x)));
  s.m=m;
  s.i=i;
  s.x=x;
  ```

  And in C:

  ```
  /* Example of initmystruct with no error checking */
  /* int is the size type assuming it matches int32 */
  /* in the MATLAB coder.ceval call                 */
  void initmystruct (mystruct *s, int szi, int szx)
  {
      s->i = malloc(szi*sizeof(*s->i));
      s->x = malloc(szx*sizeof(*s->x));
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc for [cstructname](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.cstructname.html) the header file needs to be specified using the `'Headerfile'` input argument.

Comment: As I understand it, one only needs to deklare it over the 'HeaderFile' if it isn't included in the 'custom code' section. But I tried it, and it still wont work.